# How to filter with multiple possibly empty cells in a range as criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a range, in this case, A2:H2, be my criteria for a search but I can't figure out how to make it ignore the empty cells.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Card Bank'!A2:H, 
 {'Card Bank'!A2&
 'Card Bank'!B2&
 'Card Bank'!C2&
 'Card Bank'!D2&
 'Card Bank'!E2&
 'Card Bank'!F2&
 'Card Bank'!G2&
 'Card Bank'!H2} = A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2&H2), "Error")
```

I want it to ignore the empty cells, to my knowledge, it should be turning the empty cells to a blank space, and just output the filled ones as a single string but it just keeps erroring.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what are you after, but this is how it should look like the syntax:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Card Bank'!A2:H, {'Card Bank'!A2:A&
                                   'Card Bank'!B2:B& 
                                   'Card Bank'!C2:C&
                                   'Card Bank'!D2:D&
                                   'Card Bank'!E2:E&
                                   'Card Bank'!F2:F&
                                   'Card Bank'!G2:G&
                                   'Card Bank'!H2:H} = A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2&H2), "Error")
```

[image]

the other possibilities are:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Card Bank'!A2:H, {'Card Bank'!A2:A&
                                   'Card Bank'!B2:B& 
                                   'Card Bank'!C2:C&
                                   'Card Bank'!D2:D&
                                   'Card Bank'!E2:E&
                                   'Card Bank'!F2:F&
                                   'Card Bank'!G2:G&
                                   'Card Bank'!H2:H} = A2:A&
                                                       B2:B&
                                                       C2:C&
                                                       D2:D&
                                                       E2:E&
                                                       F2:F&
                                                       G2:G&
                                                       H2:H), "Error")
```

or:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Card Bank'!A2:H, {'Card Bank'!A2&
                                   'Card Bank'!B2& 
                                   'Card Bank'!C2&
                                   'Card Bank'!D2&
                                   'Card Bank'!E2&
                                   'Card Bank'!F2&
                                   'Card Bank'!G2&
                                   'Card Bank'!H2} = A2:A&
                                                     B2:B&
                                                     C2:C&
                                                     D2:D&
                                                     E2:E&
                                                     F2:F&
                                                     G2:G&
                                                     H2:H), "Error")
```

or:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Card Bank'!A2:H2, {'Card Bank'!A2&
                                    'Card Bank'!B2& 
                                    'Card Bank'!C2&
                                    'Card Bank'!D2&
                                    'Card Bank'!E2&
                                    'Card Bank'!F2&
                                    'Card Bank'!G2&
                                    'Card Bank'!H2} = A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2&H2), "Error")
```